# Multithreaded Python socket server CPU usage spirals out of control

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, cpu-usage

**My Situation:**

I have a python server that does the following:

Listens on port 500 (for firewall reasons), and everytime it receives a connection, spawns a thread to handle the connection. Each thread that is started will respond to client input with a few methods that are mostly database interaction (I actually use the Django ORM, as my server application is coupled with a Django website).

I'd like to use select at some point (and ultimately, Twisted), but right now, I can't, so i'll have to go with this.

**My problem:**

For some reason I can't seem to understand, the server's CPU usage sometime spirals totally out of control and goes up to 200% CPU usage (we're running on a dual core), making it even pretty difficult to ssh in to stop it.

What I don't understand is that it usually does not happen during operation (If I have one or multiple clients connected, the CPU usage stays *very* low), but once all clients have disconnected, my server goes up to 200% CPU usage.

This led me to believe that the problem is not in the worker threads (If they didn't die properly, I'd rather expect a massive RAM usage than a CPU one), but in the server's accept method.

Up to now, I've been using this code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
logger.warning('Started - listening on {0}:{1}'.format(host, port))

while True:
    (newsocket, clientaddr) = s.accept() 
    logger.info('Received connection from {0}:{1}'.format(clientaddr[0], clientaddr[1]))
    WorkerThread(newsocket, clientaddr, timeout).start()
```

I can't really grasp what could be going wrong here, but I thought that maybe I should use the following syntax:

```
while True:
    (newsocket, clientaddr) = s.accept() 
    logger.info('Received connection from {0}:{1}'.format(clientaddr[0], clientaddr[1]))
    wk = WorkerThread(newsocket, clientaddr, timeout)
    wk.start()
```

I've seen this written a lot more often than what I've doing up to now.

Does anyone of you knows whether this could cause a problem such as the one I'm describing?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The problem you are referring to does not seem to be in this part. There seems to be a tight loop in the code executed after the clients disconnect.

Comment: Seems like you might be wanting twisted. Rather than cooking your own let someone else do the hard work for you! [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)

Comment: Well, whenever the clients disconnect, the thread's run method does finish, then thread dies, doesn't it? As for twisted, I can't really re-write all my code at the current moment unfortunately.

Comment: There is nothing to re-write, twisted is dead simple. You just move all your code to the retrospective methods in twisted. E.g. `connectionMade` will contain your code for handling new connections. It will save you alot of haste and make your code much cleaner.

Comment: I heard so, yes, and I have been planning on moving on to twisted on the long run, but at the moment it's not really an option to me unfortunately. Do you know of any introduction to twisted except the genesis of finger?